# UDP Bind Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, udp

I am trying to set up a UDP communication link between 2 computers.  One computer is running the client app and the other is running the server app.  The client app gives the error:

**You must call the Bind method before performing this operation.**

Here is my code below for the client below and I have commented where the error occurs:

```
 public delegate void ShowMessage(string message);
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
    Int32 port = 11000;
    public ShowMessage myDelegate;
    Thread thread;


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }


    private void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

            //Error on this line
            byte[] content = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPoint);

            if (content.Length > 0)
            {
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(content);


                this.Invoke(myDelegate, new object[] { message });
            }

        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

source -> http://lamahashim.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-c-udpclient-send-and-receive.html

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is in the server code where you forgot to call bind

Comment: Hmm.  How do you call Bind()?  I don't see it as a method for udpclient class.  I don't know if its server side or not because the client crashes on start up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the udpclient what port to listen to. The IPEndpoint you pass the receive method can be set to anything you like, since it gets populated with the senders details. It does not direct the udpclient to listen to port 11000. In affect you're trying to listen to port 0, which instructs the udpclient to pick it's own port.

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx

You'll see the constructor is called with the port to listen on.

Comment: I will keep experimenting.  Thank you.

Comment: By specifying no port argument at all he isn't even specifying zero by default, just an unbound socket. Zero would not give that error.

Comment: The documentation seems to state otherwise. From the docs on the default constructor "This constructor creates a new UdpClient and allows the underlying service provider to assign the most appropriate local IPv4 address and port number."

Answer (score 9):

I believe you need to call `Bind` on the listening server first:

```
udpServer.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000));
```

Comment: Lester, the thing is that the listening server hasn't even started up yet.  Maybe I need to put some type of condition in because the client immediately starts listening on load.

Comment: This is useful when ExclusiveAddressUse property needs setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tryed to solve with `Bind`, but there was a restriction of this method:

- After you create the `udpClient`, you can use `Bind` to assign the desired `IPEndPoint`.
- The problem appears when you try to assign again to other `IPEndPoint` to the same `udpClient` afterwords: it will give an error. I guess it would happen in the code you wrote as example (because of the loop). To solve this situation you must close the udpClient  `udpClient.Close()` and generate again  `udpClient.new()` then you can use again the `Bind`method and asign a new `IPEndPoint`.

The reason is that the `Bind` method works only with a new `udpClient` which has a `IPEndPoint=null`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

well.. I didn't make a lot of search.. but I used this and it worked :

```
UdpClientv4.Client.Connect(ipEndPointv4);
```

I used Connect instead of Bind. May be Connect is calling Bind.